# JavaScript remove element from multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form where I have a select box and a drop down menu with two buttons and a text field. Enter an item into the text field and it gets added to BOTH the select box above AND the drop down menu. I can figure out how to remove the selected item from the select box but how do I ALSO remove it from the drop down menu??

Working [JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/4uBYf/)

NOTE: On the actual form these will be on different tabs so you won't be able to see them at the same time, the list just needs to populate from one area to the other.

CSS

```
#sbox {
overflow: hidden;
width: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
        <select id="sbox" name="selectbox" size="5"></select>
    <BR>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="DeleteProbs();">Delete Selected Problem</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2" valign="top"><p>To add a problem to the list, type it in the New Problem text field and then click &quot;Add to List&quot;. To remove a problem, click it in the list, then click, &quot;Delete Selected Problem&quot;<P>
    <strong>New Problem</strong><P>
    <input type="text" id="ProbAreaFrom">
     <P>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ProbListBtn" onclick="ListProbs();">Add to List</button>
    </p>

    Problem being detailed:<BR>
     <select name="select" id="dbox">
     </select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ListProbs() {
var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = txt1
    x.add(option);
     ListProbs2();       
    } 

function ListProbs2() {
var y = document.getElementById("dbox");
    var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = txt1
    y.add(option);
    ProbAreaFrom.value="";      
}     

function DeleteProbs() {
var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
    if (x.options[i].selected) {
        x.options[i].remove();
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function DeleteProbs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
    var y = document.getElementById("dbox");
    var val;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if (x.options[i].selected) {
            val = x.options[i].value;
            x.options[i].remove();
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < y.options.length; i++) {
        if (y.options[i].value == val) {
            y.options[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

working fiddle. Added a button to remove selected item from select element. The function's name is

**DeleteProbs2**

http://jsfiddle.net/4uBYf/2/

```
   function ListProbs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
        var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = txt1
        x.add(option);
         ListProbs2();       
    } 

function ListProbs2() {
    var y = document.getElementById("dbox");
        var txt1 = document.getElementById("ProbAreaFrom").value;
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = txt1
        y.add(option);
        ProbAreaFrom.value="";      
    }     

function DeleteProbs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if (x.options[i].selected) {
            x.options[i].remove();
        }
    }
}


function DeleteProbs2() {
    var index = $('#dbox').get(0).selectedIndex;
    $('#dbox option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();

}
```

html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  colspan="2" valign="top">
        Problem List:<BR />

        <select id="sbox" name="selectbox" size="5"></select>
        <BR>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="DeleteProbs();">Delete Selected Problem</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" valign="top"><p>To add a problem to the list, type it in the New Problem text field and then click &quot;Add to List&quot;. To remove a problem, click it in the list, then click, &quot;Delete Selected Problem&quot;<P>
        <strong>New Problem</strong><P>
        <input type="text" id="ProbAreaFrom">
         <P>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ProbListBtn" onclick="ListProbs();">Add to List</button>
        </p>

        Problem being detailed:<BR>
         <select name="select" id="dbox">
         </select>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="test" onclick="DeleteProbs2();">remove from select</button>

    </td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

update for your request (first button removes from both elements)

http://jsfiddle.net/4uBYf/5/

```
function DeleteProbs() {
    var x = document.getElementById("sbox");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
        if (x.options[i].selected) {
            var text=$( "#dbox option:selected" ).text();

             $('#dbox option').filter(function () { return $(this).html() == text; }).remove();            
            x.options[i].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I didn't want to introduce a new button I want to append the DeleteProbs function to include removing the selected item also from the drop down menu. Is it possible?

Comment: Got an answer but if there's a way to combine functions ListProbs() and ListProb2() I'd be interested.

Comment: I see your update the remove button isn't there but the actual selected element isn't removed. You can see the actual answer by @encoder above. I've given you a vote up for your help thanks much appreciated.

Comment: My code remove the same item from either elements. If you want I update my answer to get this goal. You can do this without any for cycle with jquery. Happy to help you